# How to cleanup Nuxt js extra div containers?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

this is my example page:

[image]

This is the Nuxt layout:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

And this is what's produced by the Nuxt compiler:

[image]

As you can see, there are several, useless, extra containers. Is there any way to get rid of them in Nuxt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been mentioned in nuxt's github issues [#3811](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3811) and [#1792](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1792)

You cannot remove `<div id="__nuxt">` as it is the root node for mounting Vue instance. The Same goes for the `<div id="__layout">`, it is not removable.

You can still modify the application name with the variable `globalName` configuration option (see pull [#4012](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/4012)).

Comment: Clément - I know it's not your fault, but it is so, so, SO tiring that we cannot control, as a very basic, fundamental level, the semantic structure of, for lack of a better term, a damn blank white html page. It is craptacular that things are wrapped within 'div' which has zero meaning in any given state. Zero. FFS at least put it in an existing HTML element that means something, and can be re-used, like 'section', or even 'article' (tho there are requirements expected using the last one).  Thanks for reading, I owe you a coffee/beer/your happy liquid for listening to my rant.

Comment: This has been renamed. Currently on Nuxt 3.2 nuxt.config.js: ```export default { app: { rootId: '...' }}```

Comment: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config/#rootid